# Understanding HTTP chatter between TypeScript BotFramework & Emulator

Tags: node.js, localhost, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm working with Microsoft's Virtual Assistant Bot Framework solution in typescript and using the Bot Framework emulator to test it locally. Setting breakpoints in the Virtual Assistant solution causes the onboarding card to be rendered multiple times once the initial execution completes.

I'm attempting to understand what's happening here, and how an apparent delay in code execution could cause so many requests?

Here's what I see in the Bot Framework emulator while stepping through the code. [image]

Can anyone elaborate on how the framework corresponds with the Emulator after receiving a request? Additionally, any recommendations for a community better tailored to general BotFramework discussion would be helpful.

Comment: I'll start looking into this. So that I can better repro, can you provide which file and line you're setting breakpoints on that's causing this?

Comment: I'm stepping through the Index.ts, dialogbot.ts, maindialog.ts, and routerDialog files. I believe the routerDialog file breakpoint causes the issue and I notice continueDialog/onContinuedialog methods are repeated.

Comment: The overall issue I'm attempting to trackdown is that line 271 in mainDialog.ts that returns 'InterruptionAction.NoAction' isnt hit. As a result, I don't get a response to my name after being asked "what is your name" by the Virtual Assistant demo. The code never hits the finishOnboardingDialog step.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. My *guess* is that since you're delaying, you're hitting directline's policy of sending a 502 error after 15 seconds of not hearing back from the bot. I don't see the 502s in your Emulator log, but I believe this might be affecting the bot, still. If you can post exact steps to repro, I can likely help more. However, please include the code you're breaking on...our line numbers don't seem to match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard my last comment. I was able to replicate this. Here's what's happening for the specific issue of receiving multiple welcome cards:

While your breakpoint is set, the bot is unable to respond. After some time (I believe 15 seconds), Emulator will attempt to re-initiate the conversation by sending the two `conversationUpdate`s again. This is channel- and client-specific. You will not see this behavior if you test with [a WebChat sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#samples-list). Both Emulator and WebChat use the WebChat channel, but its Emulator that implements the retry and causes the multiple `conversationUpdate`s to fire during a delay.

[This is basically how bot communication works:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

[image]

---

Regarding other communities:

- The Microsoft Bot Framework team prefers that **how to** questions be submitted on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%23botframework). The official [Bot Framework Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/README.md) repos are the preferred platform for submitting **bug fixes** and **feature requests**.

  - We look at tickets every business day morning so response time is usually decent
- [Gitter](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/BotBuilder?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link) is probably the next best, although response rate varies.
- There's also some [Community Repos](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity) for unofficial extensions